# How to get the Enter key within a textbox to trigger a function and not the first/default button

Tags: jquery, button, textbox, keycode, enter

I am trying to get the Enter key to trigger a function when it is pressed when inside a certain textbox, and not trigger the first or default button.

You can see an example of what is happening here: http://jsfiddle.net/cutsomeat/WZ6TM/1/

If you press other keys you will get an alert box with the keycode, yet if you press the Enter key you will not get the alert box with the keycode, but rather the alert box within the button click event.

Obviously the Enter key is trigger the button. Is there a way to avoid this and instead, capture the Enter key in the keyup event, then trigger another function?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#myText').on("keypress", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("Enter pressed");
            return false; // prevent the button click from happening
        }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ6TM/3/)

Comment: `.live()` is depriciated now. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: better to use `bind()` instead of `on()` or worst `live()`

Comment: Use `on()`. `bind()` is now depreciated.

Answer (score 50):

Use `.on()` as `.live()` has been [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".myText", function(e) {
     if (e.which == 13) {
         //do some stuff
     }
});
```

Answer (score 21):

Do `e.preventDefault()` in keyDown to avoid default action of button:

```
$('#myText').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

Comment: Just change if (e.keyCode = 13) to if (e.keyCode == 13)

Answer (score 12):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myText').keypress(function(e) {
        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {  // detect the enter key
            $('#myButton').click(); // fire a sample click,  you can do anything
        }
    });

    $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
        alert('Button click activated!');
    });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WZ6TM/335/)**

For live elements use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('keypress', '#myText', function(e) {

        if ( e.keyCode == 13 ) {  // detect the enter key
            $('#myButton').click(); // fire a sample click,  you can do anything
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#myButton', function(e) {
        alert('Button click activated!');
    });

});
```

Comment: I would have liked to +1 this but you really should explain why keyup is better than keydown/keypress